# C++ | Templates and const type

Tags: c++, templates, constants

I have a declaration of a class in an .hpp file:

```cpp
template <typename Ressource, typename Identifier> class RessourceHolder {
public:
  void load(Identifier id, const std::string& filename);

  Ressource& get(Identifier id);
  const Ressource& get(Identifier id) const;


private:
  void insert(Identifier id, std::unique_ptr<Ressource> resource);


private:
  std::map<Identifier, std::unique_ptr<Ressource>> mRessourceMap;
};

template class RessourceHolder<sf::Texture, Textures::ID>;
typedef RessourceHolder<sf::Texture, Textures::ID> TextureHolder;
```

which include explicit instantiation for `RessourceHolder<sf::Texture,Textures::ID>`.

And I have the implementation of it in a separate .cpp file.
The problem is the following :
Later on I define a const `TextureHolder` and it raises the following error : 
`` undefined reference to `RessourceHolder<sf::Texture, Textures::ID>::get(Textures::ID) const `` 
Why?

EDIT : 
As asked, the point where the problem arise (hpp file):

```cpp
class Agent{
  public :
  Agent(TextureHolder const& textures);
  void setTexture();
  const TextureHolder& mTextures;
  private :
  sf::Sprite mSprite;
};
```

(cpp file)

```
Agent::Agent(TextureHolder const& textures) : mTextures(textures){
  setTexture();
}
void Agent::setTexture(){
  mSprite.setTexture(mTextures.get(toTextureID(mType)));
}
```

When I remove the const specifier in agent,  I don't have an error anymore

Comment: You are explicitly instantiating the class template but not its functions. I believe you would have to do the explicit instantiation of the class _after all its methods have been defined_ in order for those to be also explicitly instantiated along with the class.

Comment: There are other possible problems with the code you show, but for now you need to edit your question to include a [mcve] to show us. How do you define your member functions? Also please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file). Please include a [mcve]. The error message is just what I would expect from the code you show, there is no definition of the method and unless you show it I wont believe you :P

Comment: As for your other possible problem, an explicit instantiation definition can only exists *once* in all of your program. If the definition is in a header file then it will be defined in all [*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) where that header file is included.

Comment: PS: Resource only has one "s".

Comment: Oups, french mistake

Comment: Works here: [Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/HyyqgQ4LV)

Answer (score 0):

On a basic level, instantiating a template class only instantiates the class definition, not the definitions of the member functions.

Now, explicit instantiation of a class template *does* also explicitly instantiate the direct (non-base-class, non-template) members:

> [[temp.explicit]#10](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.explicit#10) (emphasis mine)
>
> An **explicit instantiation that names a class template specialization** is also an **explicit instantiation** of the same kind (declaration or definition) **of each of its members** (not including members inherited from base classes and members that are templates) that has not been previously explicitly specialized in the translation unit containing the explicit instantiation, provided that the associated constraints, if any, of that member are satisfied by the template arguments of the explicit instantiation ([temp.constr.decl], [temp.constr.constr]), except as described below.
> [ Note: In addition, it will typically be an explicit instantiation of certain implementation-dependent data about the class.
> — end note
>  ]

<sup>Note:

Expl. inst. *declaration* = `extern template MyClass<Args>;`, expl. inst. *definition* = `template MyClass<Args>;`</sup>

**But**, this is only done for members that are actually **defined** at the point of instantiation:

> [[temp.explicit]#11](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.explicit#11) (emphasis mine)
>
> An explicit instantiation definition that names a class template specialization explicitly instantiates the class template specialization and is an explicit instantiation definition of **only those members that have been defined at the point of instantiation**.

Since you did the explicit instantiation definition in the header (which is included by the source file), the definitions of the member functions come *after* your explicit instantiation of the class template, so those functions are *not* also explicitly instantiated.

It is therefore advisable to only perform (non-`extern`) explicit instantiation of a class template at the end of the source file that fully defines everything in it. The header file is certainly the wrong place.